# Using same form and form_for in Rails with nested resources in namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a resource that's accessible both with and without a namespace.

```
# routes.rb
resources :foo
namespace :admin do
  resources :foo
end
```

I want to use the same `_form` partial in both cases, but `form_for` requires a different argument depending upon the controller.

Should I set the `form_for` argument in the controllers?

```
# foo_controller.rb
def set_foo
  @form_for_arg = @foo
end

# admin/foo_controller.rb
def set_foo
  @form_for_arg = [:admin, @foo]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the common features of the form inside the partial, and wrap it in the individual `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, foo] do |f| %>
  <%= render "foos/form", f: f %>
<% end %>
```

And:

```
<%= form_for [foo] do |f| %>
  <%= render "foos/form", f: f %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Will `f` be available in that partial? Wouldn't I need to use `render "foos/form", f: f`

Comment: My mistake. My original answer didn't have the local variable passing that you need: `f: f`. You can also do: `render partial: "foos/form", locals: { f: f }` but I prefer the shorter version.